# Performance comparison of Quartz and pooling with system timer

Tags: .net, timer, windows-services, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

We're approaching a very common problem (we presume at least), but surprisingly could not find many choices. For a business application, we have an ASP.NET MVC application as upfront UI portal, equipped with several MSMQ/Windows services to carry out heavy duties, e.g. syncing with external accounting systems.

We hope to introduce a new service to run time-based tasks. For instance, for a purchase order in the system, it has an expected goods delivery time. Six hours before that time, the service needs to run a check to see if we received the goods or not and react accordingly.

We have two approaches:

Approach 1: define jobs statically and run them based on specific time interval. Jobs could be added/removed at run time with help of MEF framework.

Approach 2: run Quartz.Net as a Windows services and feed task with its schedule through MSMQ.

We have some ideas about these two approaches' pro's and con's:

- Efficiency:

Using approach 1: in the example mentioned above, it means we need to look up all purchase orders and check them all. While with approach 2, there is only one job scheduled at one particular time for one purchase order.

- Accuracy:

Approach 1 can hardly assure accuracy and the missing margin depends on the time interval jobs run

- Flexible schedule:

Approach 2 could provide very flexible schedule thanks to its support for Cron-like trigger

- Performance: (this is our major uncertainty)

We have concerns for Quartz regarding the performance/stress it could carry, since we could theoretically throw tens of thousands of jobs to the scheduler.

Unclear about Quartz implementation, we are aware though that keep creating timers is not ideal (if not unacceptable) for heavy duties.

Q1: So how does Quartz manage huge amount of jobs and fire them accurately without too much overhead caused by timers?

Q2: Could anyone shed some light on the magic under the hood? Or would Quartz degrade when jobs start to pile up?

Q3: Is there any other better approach for the need we have?

Answer (score 0):

A third option is to maintain a database of upcoming jobs to run. Each record in the database contains a datetime when it is due, a type and some id. One (or many) workers poll the database and grabs (atomically) the next due (or overdue) item, loads the appropriate worker class (based on the type) and calls it with the id.

Each worker task can queue up additional future work items, can reschedule itself if it is unable to run, can simply go away if it no longer has any work to do (maybe the original purchase order has been deleted), ...

Advantages:

1. You can monitor work waiting to be done / running / failed easily
2. You can retry failed work (work that started but did not complete)
3. You can scale out workers easily (more threads or processors)
4. Easy to configure (just another table)

Answer (score 0):

There exists one more option called Hangfire service, you create a windows service and schedule using Cron tab expression.